# Object I was sculpting disappeared in Sculpt mode, how do I get it back?

Tags: sculpt

-I was sculpting a head in Sculpt mode on Blender 2.90

-When I attempted to zoom (ctrl +) I may have pressed the wrong button and the whole object disappeared

-I tried to pull up another object in Sculpt mode without any success

-Both objects are visible in the Layout mode and every other mode except Sculpt mode

-This is what I see in Sculpt mode
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're in ***Local View***. This hides all other objects. It can happen that you selected another object or deleted the local object, and now the view shows nothing or always the wrong object. This happened a few times to me and I wondered where my stuff was gone.

To exit this view press <kbd>Numpad</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or use the menu: *View → Local View → Toggle Local View*

Hope that helps...